# Using different time than local machine

Tags: c#

I have a C# app that is running on windows server. But the time of that server is incorrect (timezone is fine).

How can I force my C# process to sync itself to a time server in a way that the DateTime.Now will return real time but without changing local machine time.

I cannot change all the 'DateTime.Now' uses in my code because there are too many. In adddition, there are external .net DLLs that need to use the same DateTime value.

Comment: Can you just enable automatic synchronization of time on your server? This seems like the only correct solution.

Comment: The server has automatic synchronization but some other local system on the server is modifying the time few minutes after it is synced. So i thought that maybe dot net has some internal clock system that can be synced an configured regardless of the surrounding OS clock configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I force my C# process to sync itself to a time server in a way that the DateTime.Now will return real time but without changing local machine time.

You can't:

> [`DateTime.Now` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netframework-4.8)
>
> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the **current date and time on this computer**, expressed as the local time.

Internally, on Windows, this calls the [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimeasfiletime) or [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime) function. In other words, you can't trivially circumvent `DateTime.Now` returning the machine's time.

Sure, using [detours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663785/how-to-change-the-value-of-datetime-utcnow-for-a-process-or-thread) or [Moles](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/pex-and-moles-isolation-and-white-box-unit-testing-for-net/) (superseded by Fakes in VS2012 and IntelliTest in VS2015 [Enterprise license required], but see [the VS 2008/2010 downloads](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/Peli)) you can re-route those Windows API or .NET API calls, but you generally don't want to.

Instead ask the server owner to set up proper time synchronization using NTP.